# The future of Async Apex - everything Queueable?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, future, asynchronous, roadmap

I know that this is a somewhat opinion based question but there is definitely interest in the community in where the Roadmap goes.

Do I get the blogs and communities and blogs right that we are currently in a phase between old and new Async world that will one day be like this:

1. No `@future` anymore => use `Queueable()`
2. Single Batch jobs will be Queueables that can be monitored on their own
3. `FlexQueue` will merge with Standard queue its features are usable using Apex (reordering, aborting, monitoring)
4. Scheduling will just be a feature (another implements) for a `Queueable` job and schedules jobs will be in the same queue as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't read anything to this effect, but I certainly hope that this is not precisely the case. It sounds like a bleak future to me. Here's my stance on this:

> No @future anymore => use Queueable()

If salesforce.com has a heart, they won't do this. @future is light-weight compared to Queueable. It doesn't give a job ID, doesn't require that we construct an object, don't store entire memory graphs (minimal serialization), and doesn't require an additional call to a system method. @future is perfectly suited for lightweight asynchronous tasks, as it was meant to do. Also, they should have their own queue as they do today. They're supposed to be so lightweight that they don't interfere with the heavier Queueable and Batchable interfaces.

> Single Batch jobs will be Queueables that can be monitored on their own

No, you could convert Batchables to Queueables, but you wouldn't necessarily want to. Using Queueable has several limitations dealing with callouts, mixing Setup and non-Setup DML, and having a way to perform a limit-proof "finally". Batchable is a tool that can be used, and until salesforce implements either [Allow a special type of async call that only fires during transaction failures](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BvAAI), [Create an exception class that throws warnings for governor limits](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5CAAAY), or [atexit" support for Apex Code](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BWAAY), I can't seriously consider Queueable as a total replacement even for single-execution Batchable calls. I've tried this, and it's an utter disaster. We need better ways of handling governor limits besides an absolute, immediate termination.

> FlexQueue will merge with Standard queue its features are usable using Apex (reordering, aborting, monitoring)

I'm surprised they haven't done this yet. The current design means that if all five slots are being used, you have to wait behind those five processes, even if you know that all five of them are actually going to be running for two days straight, and the job you want to run would take 10 seconds flat. Having two queues makes little sense. In fact, we should be able to willingly place a new Batchable on hold during creation, even if any of the five standard slots are free. However, it's all safe-harbor or speculation, and no idea when, or if, they'll get around to it.

> Scheduling will just be a feature (another implements) for a Queueable job and schedules jobs will be in the same queue as well

I'm sure this is pure conjecture at this point. I also wouldn't want Queueable and Schedulable to exist in the same queue, unless I can also schedule Queueable the way I can schedule Schedulable, in which case, they may as well drop Schedulable entirely. I don't think they can do this very easily, because such a change would require every developer everywhere to retool their code. This completely breaks backwards compatibility. More likely, they'll have a new Queueable2 interface that will combine the best of Queueable and Schedulable, and deprecate the original interfaces, or perhaps come up with a new name (just call the ScheduledQueue interface, please?).

Comment: `@future` also does not consume dml limits, which `Queueables` do, correct?

Comment: @AdrianLarson All three interfaces, Queueable, Batchable, and Schedulable, seem to prevent callouts when used, so you have to save them for last. Also, I think they still haven't fixed the bug where a callout and a Queuable called in the same Queueable transaction causes an error (cannot callout with pending commit if you callout after, or cannot chain Queueable if you callout first).

Comment: Gotcha. My question was simply if creating the job record (whether `Queueable` or `Batchable`) is a dml operation, which makes `@future` less of a `Limits` risk.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I actually haven't noticed that specifically, but I don't usually pay attention to limits until I start getting warnings in my log. I'll test this and come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson They don't seem to use DML statements, so there's only the usual limits to worry about (e.g. max flex queue size versus maximum number of future calls per transaction). That said, the Batchable queue is a lot smaller than the future queue, which has no inherent limit besides the per-day limits shared across all async code and the 50 per transaction limit.